Connect multiple A&H QU mixers as aggregate devices
I am looking to purchase a Studio M2 for our recording studio. Before proceeding I need to confirm that the M2 Studio can connect an Allen & Heath QU32 mixer and a QU-PAC mixer to the M2 as an aggregate audio interface.
Note: This is not possible on a Windows machine with ASIO4ALL, as the A&H Windows driver cannot distinguish between the two mixers.
I am hoping that on a Mac, this can be done as there are no drivers required on a Mac.

What does the product documentation say? Have you reached out to the manufacturer and asked them?

Thanks  @agarza.  The product documentation is silent on the issue. I have tried A&H technical support with mixed results. Attempted to escalate to tier 3 support with much success.

Luke at A&H ran a test and was able to successfully aggregate a QU-32 and a QU-PAC, so I’m going to move ahead with a M2 Studio.  Will post any updates here :)
